# Typescript error in docker build during npm run build

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, npm

Facing a strange problem in docker build for typescript.

Docker file i have used as multistage build.

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine3.10 as build
COPY package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm i --unsafe-perm --no-optional && npm cache clean --force

RUN mkdir -p /home/app && mkdir -p /home/app/ui && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /home/app && cp -a /tmp/ui/node_modules /home/app/ui/node_modules
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY . .
RUN npm run build && cd ui && npm run build
```

but the same works if i run npm run build in local machine instead of docker

Error while running npm run build inside dockerfile

> "
>   error TS2322: Type 'Pick< ILocationValue, "address" | "_id" | "latitude" | "longitude" | "timezone" >' is not assignable to type 'ILocationValue'.
>   "

below is ILocationValue

```
interface ILocationValue extends MongoDoc, ILoc {}
```

and

```
interface ILoc
{
    longitude: number;
    latitude: number;
    timezone: string;
    address: string;
}
```

Can someone help on this or if this docker related or TS related issue?

Comment: on your local machine, clean up node_modules and `npm install` again, just to double check

Comment: HI @germanio Attempted , but still in local able to build ,but error from npm run build inside docker build

Comment: how about retrieving package-lock.json from the image and compare it to your local? since it can't assign Pick<ILocationValue> to ILocationValue perhaps there's a difference in dependencies versions

Comment: I tried deleting package-lock.json in local repository, node_modules and did npm install && npm run build and it was success again ! But the same fails yet again inside docker !

Comment: @germanio  let me see how to retrieve it from image and compare , but is there a possibility for dependency mismatch to happen cause am copying package.json and doing npm install in local and same way inside docker build, how could same package.json with same version of npm modules to install different versions ?  just curious about this wired problem happening to me !

Comment: good question! I think it's possible npm finds the best match for a given dependency in package.json... not 100% sure if node version and OS could make a difference... unless you are using in your local the exact same version than your docker image

Comment: also, you can try to mount a volume to your image, so you can access its content later

Comment: What does your Webpack config look like?

Comment: @germanio issue is due to latest version of @types/typescript had added validation and during docker build version is migrated to latest than from whats there in actual source package-lock.json .

somehow even after deleting the same doesn't simulate the same unless i update package version in host lock file and tried with npm run build and issue simulated with same set of errors in host machine also. :)

Comment: so you find the cause then? nice to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you override node_modules while executing `copy . .` with ones from your host. Try running command on clean repository or add node_modules to docker ignore.